# Display multiple plots with Plots.jl

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I currently have two vectors, x and y which I plot separately as in

```
using Plots
pyplot() # chooses pyplot background
x = rand(100); y = rand(100)
plt1 = plot(x)
display(plt1)
plt2 = plot(y)
display(plt2)
```

I have also tried the `gui()` and `gui(plt1)` functions, but these have a similar effect as the `display(plt1)` function.  Also note that I am running this in a file (hence the necessity of the `display()` function).  I have also tried similar code in the REPL, which has the same problem of only displaying the last plot I call.

My question is how do I display two different figures at the same time?  My current implementation has `plt2` overwrite `plt1`, so I am not able to see them at the same time.  Note that I am not looking for making a subplot, but rather two distinct figures.  Is there a `figure()` function similar to Matplotlib which allows declaration of separate figures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use the phrase `plt2 = plot(y, reuse = false)`

Comment: I am creating scatter plots using (scatter) on version .4.5, and I only get the second of the two scatter plots, as well; each time I run the scatter using the above modification, the figure number is incremented

Comment: You can use legacy versions of Plots on Julia versions <0.6, but they are unsupported and may have bugs. I'd strongly suggest you update julia to the current version.